# Python "calculator" cant get it right, invalid syntax

Tags: python

First time i've come here, and i would appreciate som help.

```
version = str(input("Select version: A B C D"))
number = int(input("Enter your first number"))
number2 = int(input("Enter you second number"))
if version == A:
    print(number * number2)
```

So i dont know what im doing wrong, have been trying float(input(select version: A B C D")  (im actually not rly finished with my script yet)
I want that if you press A, that it will register that to the version and print the numbers you wished for.

Comment: You're testing if `version` is the variable `A`, not if it's the string `'A'`. I recommend checking out this [introductory guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_quick_guide.htm).

Answer (score 4):

In your code A it's undefied variable. Change it to string 'A'

```
version = str(input("Select version: A B C D"))
number = int(input("Enter your first number"))
number2 = int(input("Enter you second number"))
if version == 'A':
    print(number * number2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

It means that the variable named `A` is not defined. You probably want to compare to the string `'A'`, since the `version` variable contains a string.